# Wget crawling without download file

Tags: wget

I am just trying to count how many URLs match with the pattern `x--*.html`. In this case below all files that match are being downloaded.

```
$ wget --random-wait --mirror --no-parent -A x--*.html myBaseURL &
```

Since I just want a count, is there some way to avoid transferring all these pages?

**NOTE:** I know there is a command `--delete-after`, but it still transfers.

Any ideas?

Comment: How is wget supposed to crawl a site without looking at the html pages to find all the links?

Comment: Good question. What I mean is just do not download the url that matches. But you're right, it still will download, even in memory. `--delete-after` is the best option, do you agree?

Comment: You can tell `wget` to write the files to `/dev/null`. `wget ... -O /dev/null`. That way it won't even write them to disk, it'll just drop them from the get go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not believe there's an option to do this. In order to parse the contents of these files to see if there are additional links to follow, `wget` has to download them.

Your best option will likely be to do this:

```
$ wget --random-wait --mirror --no-parent -A x--*.html myBaseURL -O /dev/null &
```

To count the matches:

```
wget --random-wait --mirror --no-parent -A x--*.html myBaseURL -O | wc -l
```

Comment: How can I know how many files matched?

Comment: @coffee - see update.